# Kotlin convert uri to filepath

Tags: android, kotlin, type-conversion, uri, filepath

I'm using Kotlin, and in converting the file uri to a file, the file uri value starts with content://, so I can't access it. So you need to know the absolute path.
There are many java codes, but the code for kotlin does not exist, so I tried to convert it, but an error occurs in kotlin. Please help me[image]

Not only Image file I want all type files
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please add the code from the screenshot as text to make it searchable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate mechanism for getting path from URI in the versions below Kitkat (`getDataColumn(...)` method will serve the purpose as gets the file path using `ContentResolver`).

In the versions above the Kitkat, we have to implement a separate logic for different file types, either they are picked from documents directory, Gallery, or downloads folder.

**URIPathHelper.kt**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.DocumentsContract
import android.provider.MediaStore

class URIPathHelper {

    fun getPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        val isKitKatorAbove = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKatorAbove && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + split[1]
                }

            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id))
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                var contentUri: Uri? = null
                if ("image" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                } else if ("video" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                } else if ("audio" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                }
                val selection = "_id=?"
                val selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs)
            }
        } else if ("content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null)
        } else if ("file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
            return uri.path
        }
        return null
    }

    fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        val column = "_data"
        val projection = arrayOf(column)
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,null)
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val column_index: Int = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                return cursor.getString(column_index)
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) cursor.close()
        }
        return null
    }

    fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority
    }
}
```

**You can later use it like**

```
val uriPathHelper = URIPathHelper()
val filePath = uriPathHelper.getPath(this, user_uri)
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot!!!!!!
I want one more question.
It works fine for image files, but not for pdf format files or other files type?. Is there a way?

Comment: For Non-media files, we have to use SAF framwork

Comment: Is it possible to add the document format (pdf, word..) in the code above?